# Webpack: How to pack all packages from packages.json

Tags: webpack

I'm trying out [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) and experiencing a beginner problem:

I've added webpack and a couple of vendor packages with `yarn`:

```
yarn add --dev webpack
yarn add highlight.js
yarn add datatables
...
```

As expected, this downloaded the vendor stuff into `node_modules` and created a `packages.json`.

How do I tell webpack

- to pack all packages from `packages.json` into one javascript file, e.g. `packs/vendor.js`?
- to pack all packages from `packages.json` into separate javascript files, e.g. `packs/highlight.js`, `packs/datatables.js` etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There might be the chance that you are not going to use all the modules that you download and you also have to consider the different type dependencies (dep, dev, peer)

Comment: We're migrating to webpack in several steps. In this intermediate phase, we need to interact with packages (for example with `hljs` from *highlight.js*) from our own scripts, which are not managed by webpack, yet.

Comment: You can try to use the `CommonsChunkPlugin` (there's a section where it tells you how to bundle modules inside package.json) but you consider that webpack will bundle those modules **only if you use them inside your project**